# What is a .tlc file?

Tags: matlab, arduino, simulink

Hi im quite new in this stuff. I am trying to get an arduino board to run with a stepper motor and Simulink model but when I try to run my Simulink model on the arduino i keep getting an error that says that a .tlc file is missing. ( I am using Matlab R2013a )

My question is can someone explain in a simple way what is this .tlc file where is it used and why ?

And do I need to write one for my program to run.

I have posted in more detail my problem with the arduino in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22938827/arduino-stepper-motor-control-with-simulink) question.

Comment: I don't think it is a duplicate because here I ask for information regarding tlc files and how they are generated. I only provided the link of the other topic for additional information if needed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

TLC (Target Language Compiler) files are used to customize the code building process.  They generally come in two varieties

1. System/model tlc files that help in the overall model conversion process
2. Block level tlc files which describe how individual blocks (typically S-Functions) get converted to C code.

But writing them is a very advanced maneuver, and describing them in a short answer difficult.
You should search the doc for the term "Introduction to the Target Language Compiler" and read the links from there to get a more detailed overview.

If you're getting an error about a missing tlc file from a package that you didn't author (i.e. Arduino) then you need to go back to the authors of that package and get it.
It's not something that you're going to be able to generate yourself.